# Java check whether array is full or not, and copying part of different array to another array

Tags: java, arrays

*I have only a couple hours of experience with Java.*

I want to store some information in a byte array in a for loop. However I need to know when it is full. If it is full, I'll write the content of byte array into output file and continue. How could I know that?

Here is my code: *(numbers are just an example, in my real code they're coming from some calculations)*

```
byte[] wholeBlock =new byte[1024];
byte[] checkStorage= new byte[1000];
byte[] outputStore= new byte[60]; // when this is full I need to write it into file and erase content.

for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
    if(wholeBlock[i]==checkStorage[i]){
        // check if outputStore is full or not enough to store some number of bytes
        // if there is enough space        
            // now I want to store 3 bytes starting from i'th member of checkStorage into     outputStore. I also want to know how could I do that. 
        // otherwise
            // write the content of outputStore into file 
    }
}
```

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun sorry for that. I've edited it

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Oh yes, you are right! I delete my comment.

Comment: Now could we focus on my real problem ?

Comment: I've already said that I'have just a couple hours experience with Java dont be rude

Comment: Arrays in Java have no concept of "fullness".  You would need to maintain a separate counter variable.  (Or better, just use a collection like `ArrayList` to manage everything for you.)

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your problem. But what are you doing is well handled in `BufferedWriter`'s write http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(char[], int, int).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know how "full" an array is, youl´ll need to have a "int counter" or something like that
and increase it everytime you add something to the array

Comment: There is no method for that ?

Comment: No! there is NOT method. @TheGost consider also ByteBuffer class

Comment: Technically, the array is full all the time. A Array allocated with "new byte[10]" has 10 bytes, no matter how you look at it. And each byte has a value. The real question is, which bytes have values from your assignments and which not?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine arrays like a row of boxes, each holding a thing of the defined type.

If you ask for an array `outputStore = new byte[60]` you're getting a row of 60 boxes, each holding the **default** value of `byte` type (which is `0b`).

The problem with arrays is, to the program it's *always full*. It always has all the boxes filled with a byte, and can't tell you which boxes were filled by *default* and which were filled by *you*.

**You** have the responsibility of defining and storing that information. And you do that by maintaining counters or index variables of type `int` (or `long`, if `int` is not big enough).

As a beginner, you may want to stick to using arrays to gain a good understanding of Java principles. For this, you should write out your code similar to the following:

```
byte[] wholeBlock =new byte[1024];
byte[] checkStorage= new byte[1000];
byte[] outputStore= new byte[60]; // when this is full I need to write it into file and erase content.
int outputStoreIndex = 0;

for(int i=0;i<256;i++){ //do you mean to use wholeBlock.length or checkStorage.length?
    if(wholeBlock[i]==checkStorage[i]){
        // check if outputStore is full or not enough to store some number of bytes
        // if there is enough space        
        if (outputStoreIndex < (outputStore.length-2)) { //the 2 accommodates i+2 below
            // now I want to store 3 bytes starting from i'th member of checkStorage into     outputStore
            outputStore[outputStoreIndex] = checkStorage[i];
            outputStore[outputStoreIndex+1] = checkStorage[i+1];
            outputStore[outputStoreIndex+2] = checkStorage[i+2];
            outputStoreIndex += 3;
        // otherwise
        } else {
            // write the content of outputStore into file 
            /* here you can write the bytes */
            //remember to write bytes from outputStore only up to (outputStoreIndex-1)
            //to "erase" outputStore, simply reset the index to 0:
            outputStoreIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

As you get better at Java, explore into options mentioned by others such as `ArrayList` and `ByteBuffer`. These greatly help reduce the time you spend debugging your applications as they help automate what you would be manually doing with an array.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: ByteBuffer class of the nio package

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

here an example

```
    byte[] myByte = {1,1,1,1,1}; //5bytes
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 256 );
    buffer.put(myByte);

    System.out.println(buffer.capacity()); // it return 256

    System.out.println(buffer.position()); // it return 5

    buffer.put(myByte);
    System.out.println(buffer.position()); // it return 10

    System.out.println(buffer.remaining()); // it return 256 - 10

    buffer.rewind();
    System.out.println(buffer.position()); // it return 0
```